# Content Type - turn in to Form on front end to be used

Tags: forms, nodes

Im fairly new to Drupal. 
Coming from Joomla.
I created content type that works flawlesly and now i would like to take that form thats in the admin area and show it on front end for public to fill out.

Is this easely possible or do i need to use the Form API and rebuild the form and some how map to the fields in DB ?

Please let me know whats the best way to go about this.

Thanks In advance

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.anilsagar.com/content/drupal-7-tutorial-part-11-drupal-7-user-concepts-explained-adding-new-users-roles-permission) may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under /admin/people/permissions you can grant a role access to create/edit/delete content of a specific type.

Look for the sub-heading **Node** and pick your content type from any listed. I've highlighted Poll in my example.

[image]

[Click here for full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItwYr.png)

Here is the guide for roles and permissions from Drupal:
https://drupal.org/node/120614

Comment: Are you kidding me, you have just saved me hours of work. I think Drupal just became the #1 cms on my list.